# Align cross fading images

Tags: css, image

I'm very new to HTML & css. I am trying to add hovering images to my website.
This I have managed. However, I would like all my images to be of the
same size and also centered. If anyone knows how to change the
images automatically using buttons that would be better.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<style>


body {
    background-color: lightblue;


}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}


img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 180px;
}


img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;


}

            img:nth-of-type(1){
                 -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 10s linear 6s infinite;
            }
            img:nth-of-type(2){
                 -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 10s linear 4s infinite;
            }
            img:nth-of-type(3){
                 -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 10s linear 2s infinite;
            }
            img:nth-of-type(4){
                 -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 10s linear infinite;
            }

/*  Keyframes - WebKit only ------------------------------------------ */


            @-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut{

            0% { opacity:1; } 
            17% { opacity:1; } 
            25% { opacity:0; } 
            92% { opacity:0; } 
            100% { opacity:1; }

            }

</style>
</head>
<title>Badass Burgers</title>

<body>



<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="info.php">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.php">Team</a></li>
  <li><a href="Menu.php">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
 <img src='food1.jpg'>
        <img src='Food2.jpg'align="middle">
        <img src='Food3.jpg' align="middle">
        <img src='food4.jpg'align="middle">


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all of the images to be the same size, you'll need to set a fixed width and height on each image.

To center the images within a given container, you can use the CSS below.

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img class="image" src='http://lorempixel.com/400/200/' width="200" height="175" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px; // change to whatever works for you 
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

See [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jen1mn81/)